# Migration issues in sandbox

Tags: migration-tool, migration

I got a sandbox whose metadata i want to migrate to another sandbox(not belonging to the same production)

My target sandbox is  consulting partner edition and source is Enterprise Edition

I tried doing this via Eclipse IDE .But there are some issues

1-In eclipse do i need to deploy in order.Select objects first deploy,then select tabs like that?Does it automatically detect the dependancies?

2-I selected only custom objects and deployed and it showed be deployed successfully page.
But when i check in my sandbox,there is no objects there
also if i try to redo deploy i can see the same objects appearing with add option

Not sure what is happening

Comment: Have you considered using an unmanaged package? It does detect dependencies.

Comment: I agree with @greenstork, this seems like a great case for unmanaged packages